# jQuery: appendTo($('body')) dosn't work

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

```
var popupType1 = "<div id=\"layerpopuplock\" style=\"position:absolute; width:375px; height:170px; z-index:2; left: 2px; top: 50px; visibility: hidden; \">";
    popupType1 += "<table width=\"375\" border=\"1\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" bordercolor=\"#FF0000\">";
    popupType1 += "<tr><td align=\"center\" bordercolor=\"#FFFFFF\" class=\"FacetBiggerFieldCaptionTD\" id=\"popupmessagelock\" nowrap>message</td></tr>";
    popupType1 += "</table></div>";

$(popupType1).appendTo($('body'));
```

This piece of code doesn't work.

I tryied a console.log  of $('body') and I see it empty, but OF COURSE the html is already here, and the body is present.

***Which can be the reason $('body') is empty ?***

---

***SOLUTION:***

Sorry for wasting your time.
My assumption was wrong: *html is already here*

I corrected in this way and now it goes, sorrry !!!!

```
$(function() {
    ... previous code ...
});
```

Comment: You can omit the $() from 'body'

Comment: You should not pass lengthy HTML strings to `$`, but use `$.parseHTML` instead. In this case, just `$("body").append(popupType1)` is the most appropriate.

Comment: I've found the problem, sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see 3 points to pay attention to:

1. concat (combine) the strings with `+=` ... `var longstr = str; longstr += str2;`
2. in `.appendTo()` use a selector instead of an object reference ... `$(..).appendTo('body');`
3. are you using a DOM-Ready handler like `jQuery.ready( ... );` to trigger your code? This handler ensures, all DOM nodes are ready while using your script and it will be inserted at the right place (not other nodes getting in the way, even tho the body node exists) [jQuery API: .ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

additionally to 2: you could also use `$('body').append(popupType1);`

additionally to 3: it may depend where you call your script - for example script tags within the body may behave odd adding elements.

Comment: The third option saved my life ! I didn't use the ready() handler ! Thanks !

Answer (score 8):

Replace your 2 last

```
popupType1 = ...
```

by

```
popupType1 += ...
```

to have an HTML string that makes sense.

Note also that it would be easier to see the result without the `visibility: hidden;` in the `div` style.

**[Demonstration](http://dystroy.org/stackoverflow/appendTo.html)**

Comment: I tested the code : with the += and the removal of visibility:hidden, it works perfectly.

Comment: I've found the problem, sorry, see the modified question.

Answer (score 7):

You need to do `+=` on all right now it only appends `</table></div>`

Comment: The code works, it's like dystroy says remove visibility:hidden and you'll see it on your page or change it to visibility:visible

Comment: I've found the problem, sorry, see the modified question.

Answer (score 1):

```
popupType1 += "<tr><td align=\"center\" bordercolor=\"#FFFFFF\" class=\"FacetBiggerFieldCaptionTD\" id=\"popupmessagelock\" nowrap>message</td></tr>";
popupType1 += "</table></div>";
```

You are missing the += from your last two popupType1 assignments.

Comment: I've found the problem, sorry, see the modified question.